# Installing KDE Neon 22.04 fails after locales

Tags: kde, kde-neon

Installing a fresh KDE Neon 22.04 on a Lenovo laptop to replace a pre-existing KDE Neon install.

After configuring locales the installation failed with a bad main script file. Details:

`Main script file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/networkcfg/main.py for python job networking raised an exception.`

No further details of what the exception might have been were given.

The laptop had an active internet connection at the time.

Installation aborted.

Comment: https://discuss.kde.org/t/neon-unstable-20240225-iso-broken/10860/6

Answer (score -3):

It turned out the release that I had downloaded had a bug. The issue resolved itself with a subsequent release of the distribution

Comment: It might be useful to include which version didn't work, and what's the minimum version you can confirm works